# MapStruct dependency form a cycle

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

Working with new project I run into issue of cycling dependency, that did not occurred in previous projects. The only difference is me using constructor injection rather than field injection like in previous projects. Is there any way to fix the cycling dependency?
My DAO looks like this:

```
FieldDAO{
    //other fields
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = UserDAO.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private UserDAO user;
}

UserDAO{
@OneToMany( mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = 
true)
@ApiModelProperty(notes = "User fields")
private List<FieldDAO> fieldList;
}
```

Mappers:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true), uses = {FieldMapper.class)
public interface UserMapper {

@Mapping(target = "id", expression = "java(toMap.getUserId().getId())")
UserDAO mapToEntity(User toMap,
                           @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext cycleAvoidingMappingContext);

@Mapping(target = "userId", source = "toMap", qualifiedByName = "longToObject")
User mapToDomain(UserDAO toMap,
                        @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext cycleAvoidingMappingContext);

@Named("longToObject")
default UserId fromLongToObject(UserDAO userDAO) {
    return UserId.of(userDAO.getId());
}
```

}

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true), uses = {UserMapper.class, CultivationTypeMapper.class})
public interface FieldMapper {

@Mapping(target = "id", expression = "java(toMap.getFieldId().getId())")
FieldDAO mapToEntity(Field toMap,
                     @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext cycleAvoidingMappingContext);

@Mapping(target = "fieldId", source = "toMap", qualifiedByName = "longToObject")
Field mapToDomain(FieldDAO toMap,
                  @Context CycleAvoidingMappingContext cycleAvoidingMappingContext);

@Named("longToObject")
default FieldId fromLongToObject(FieldDAO fieldDAO) {
    return FieldId.of(fieldDAO.getId());
}
```

}

Error:

```
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

 ┌─────┐
 |  userMapperImpl (field private 
 com.project.endpoints.field.management.FieldMapper           
com.project.endpoints.user.management.UserMapperImpl.fieldMapper)
 ↑     ↓
 |  fieldMapperImpl (field private 
 com.project.endpoints.user.management.UserMapper com.project.endpoints.field.management.FieldMapperImpl.userMapper)
 └─────┘
```

Comment: Can you additionally post the text of the error? Otherwise, it’s not entirely clear whether the error is related to the implementation of the mapper or other beans

Comment: I have added error message to original post